# Linking an extern static array of structs is not working correctly

Tags: c, arrays, struct, extern, static-array

I am trying to link a statically defined array of structs. I am using the extern modifier to do so. When I print out the memory address of my extern struct, it differs from the location that it appears to be in the executable.

Here is what I have:

**type.h:**

```
typedef struct tableEntry {
     const char *my_str;
     void *my_addr;
     int myint;
} my_struct;
```

**test.c:**

```
include "type.h"

my_struct my_array[] = {
    {"hello", (void*)15, 5000},
    {"world", (void*)15, 3000},
    {"abtest", (void*)15, 2000},
};
```

**main.c:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "type.h"

extern my_struct* my_array;

int main() {
    printf("array location - %p\n", my_array);
    printf("array entry 1 myint - %d\n", my_array[0].myint);
    printf("array entry 1 address - %p\n", my_array[0].my_addr);
    printf("array string location - %p\n", &(my_array[0].my_str));
    printf("array string - %s\n", my_array[0].my_str);
}
```

I compile the program like so:

```
gcc test.c main.c
```

And when I run my executable I get the following output:

```
array location - 0x4006be
array entry 1 myint - 29811
array entry 1 address - 0x6574626100646c72
array string location - 0x4006be
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

my_array's address in nm output:

```
0000000000601060 D my_array
```

As you can see, my output is not what I expect, and my_array is not linked properly (the location in the nm output differs from the location printed by the actual program).

Note: I cannot include the test.c file in my main.c. It must be linked.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change

```
extern my_struct* my_array;
```

To

```
extern my_struct my_array[];
```

You can't use `extern` to modify your array into a pointer.

Comment: Well that was easy. Thanks!

Comment: @rost0031 You didn't really address the question. See Olaf's answer.

Comment: @banach-space: OP seemed to think that it did.

Comment: @rost0031 It does indeed fix the result. Shame you don't explain why.

Comment: I did.  The OP seems to know how to handle arrays vs pointers just fine.  He just didn't know how to properly link extern arrays.  I've ran into the same problem a few years ago and I corrected the only problem he had in his code and explained why in the last sentence.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with the address of my_array is you print the *value* the pointer *contains*. But for the array, you want the address of the pointer itself (which would be the address of the first element of the array). As a pointer, however, that is still wrongly declared (wonder why the compiler does not complain).

Short:

- struct x *p;    // p is the value stored in x: "where it points to"
- struct x q[];   // q is the address of the first entry (== the address of the array).

To get the same for p, you actually would have to take `&p`, but that would be of type pointer to pointer, not the struct. This is one of the differences between arrays and pointers. Read the [**standard**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.3.2.1p3) for details.

So, use the same declaration u used in the implementation file in `main.c`. Actually, you should pack the declaration into the header `type.h` (note this can easily be confused with the standard header `type**s**.h`). This iwll also generate a warning about mismatch of declaration and definition when you compile 'type.c`. That is one of the most important uses of headers actually.

For the discrepancy between the *actual* address and the *logical* address `nm` reports: The file is loaded to RAM before execution and has to be *relocated* according to the *load address*. The address in the file is actually relative to the base address of the `.data` (initialized variables) or `.bss` (uninitialized, default to 0 variables) section which is normally 0 for each section in the file. When loaded, start address in RAM is added to these relative addresses to get the actual address. This is one reason why a program might take some time after being loaded (relocation can be quite complicated).

There is one exception to that: if you let the linker relocate the program to absolute addresses like for an bare-metal (no full-grown OS) embedded controller, `nm` shall report the same addresses as during run-time or in the debugger. Reason is that the linker actually includes the job of the run-time loader described above. As a result, the code must le loaded to the correct address range, e.g. to Flash memory.

Comment: So, would the downvoter please at least be so kind to leave a comment?

Comment: `nm` and the code report similar address with rost0031's fix. This makes your last paragraph irrelevant. (BTW, it's not me who down-voted).

Comment: @banach-space: I did not suspect you. for `nm`: similar is the same as "different" im programming. `nm` cannot show the same address, unless it's for an embedded system where ld relocs to absolute addresses. But that information is not given (neither by tag nor explicit).

Comment: It's all fair enough, but I tried the code and run `nm`, and I got identical address in both cases (on a PC rather than embedded platform). I don't really know much about loaders, but I suspect that due to VMAs (let's assume we live in Linux world), the relocation address calculated for `.data` during linking is identical to the one during execution. This way `nm` and `printf()` show identical addresses.

Comment: Can be. But actually how would that change with different `.bss` and `.data` sizes and address space randomization? Also, how would that work with a uniform address space? Perhaps nm appies some kind of relocation for the symbols already? Anyway, I actually would not rely on this for non-absolute ELF sections.

Comment: Let's leave it here. OP is happy with one of the answers, and it's been a good learning experience for me too. Cheers for the effort mate!